# Error 500 apache en centos 6

Tags: postgresql, apache, centos

Tengo un servidor de datos y otro de aplicaciones en maquinas virtuales en centos 6 que utilizan postgresql 9.1, en el de aplicaciones tengo unos archivos .war y .ear dentro de unos nodos del jboss que son las páginas a las que quiero poder conectarme, al colocar la ip del servidor de aplicaciones en un navegador de mi equipo local deberia poder acceder a las páginas que tienen almacenadas estos archivos, dos de ellos abren correctamente pero no puedo pasar del login, pero el otro me arroja error 500 y no me deja ni siquiera llegar a la pag. de login. El virtual host lo tengo configurado. Sé que es un error interno de aplicación pero me gustaría saber si es que puede ser problema de alguno de los archivos de configuración u otra cosa que este fallando, lamento la poca información, estaré atento a cualquier respuesta para poder brindar información adicional. Gracias

Comment: Si es un error 500, la forma de dar con él es buscando en el fichero error_log del servidor web.

Comment: un error 500 es un error aveces ni apache te dice bien el error... como dice @track3r verifica los logs de JBOSS y el de apache genralmente esta en` /var/logs/apache/error.log` una vez que tengas ese error publicalo mejora tu respuesta y alli nuestra ayuda sera mas efectiva

Answer (score 0):

Funcionó (más o menos) lo que pasa es que intenté abrir la página que me tiraba el error desde otro navegador y esta vez funcionó, el problema es que la pág de login que me carga esta "incompleta" o no es la que debería aparecer, pero puedo registrar un usuario e ingresar, una vez lo cerré, intenté abrirlo de nuevo y ocurrió lo mismo, en el primer navegador que intenté, apareció el error 500 pero al cambiar de navegador el error desaparece, no se cual pueda ser la causa de esto pero al menos fue un avance.